# Как расставить запятые в предложении: "Барсик наверняка домашний кот и хочет бегать по крышам"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Требуется расставить запятые в предложении: **Барсик наверняка домашний кот и хочет бегать по крышам.**

Answer (score 1):

НАВЕРНЯКА

I. нареч. *Разг.*
1. Несомненно, верно, точно. *Нельзя наверняка сказать, что опыт удался.*
2. С верным расчётом, безошибочно. *Действовать наверняка. Всё рассчитать наверняка.*

II. вводн. сл. Конечно, несомненно, разумеется. *Он, наверняка, опять опоздает. Работу, наверняка, опять придётся переделывать. Этого количества, наверняка, будет мало.*

Считается, что чаще *наверняка* – наречие, которое не обособляется:

(1) **Барсик навернякА домашний кот и хочет бегать по крышам.**
В этом случае ударение падает на наречие.

(2) **Барсик, наверняка,  домАшний кот и хочет бегать по крышам.**
При обособлении вводного слова ударение падает на слово ***домашний***.